# Excel VBA - prevent cell from changing upon edit

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to prevent a cell from being edited as I need to preserve the formula in it. The problem is, I want to copy paste a large range of values from another workbook over into my sheet, and the target range for pasting includes some cells which must not change. Thus, a simple lock option wouldn't work, as this would prevent me from doing this operation in one go.

I tried using a code wherein the cell changes back to its intended formula upon change of the cell, however, this yields an infinite loop. See simplified example below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F28")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("F28").Formula = "=if(E28=0,0,G28/E28)"
End If

End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Edit:
An automated solution that would transfer from this other workbook wouldn't work as I receive these files in various formats and workbook names.

Comment: I'm assuming you added this code to the sheet you are pasting into (rather than into a standard module for the workbook). Wrap the If/EndIf in Application.EnableEvents = False and Application.EnableEvents = True to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: @chuff, sorry, I didn't see your comments earlier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is infinite loop than here goes quite common solution for the problem. You just need to switch off events for a while and than switch them on back. Your code could looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'turns off events
    Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F28")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("F28").Formula = "=if(E28=0,0,G28/E28)"
End If
    'turns on events back
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Sub that enters the "resident" formulas. Just make a call to this sub after pasting the new values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply marlenunez. How would I do the call to another sub? Can you put down an example in code - that'd be much appreciated.